# Why does Excel say "there's [an issue] with the clipboard"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, clipboard

I had to paraphrase the error from Excel because Superuser doesn't allow "problem" in the title, which is a bit amusing in this case. The actual error, as I'm sure anyone who uses Excel is aware, is this:

> There's a problem with the clipboard, but you can still paste your content within this workbook.

I'm not asking how to solve this problem (because based on some Googling I don't think it's possible). In my decades of using computers I don't remember a single other program having problems with the clipboard, so my question is this: Why does it happen? What's the technical reason? Why is Excel different to every other program?

This happens when I'm copying cells in Excel. It doesn't happen (I think) when copying text within a cell (i.e. by editing the cell, selecting the text and copying). I can extremely reliably make it happen by copying a few cells in a row. The cells can contain anything or nothing. If I copy more than 3-5 cells within 10 seconds or so I consistently get the error.

Comment: When does Excel say that message? What's in the clipboard when it says it? If you copy something very basic, like a single letter from within Excel or a basic notepad or terminal, does Excel still complain?

Comment: @Xen2050 Good point, I updated my question.

Comment: Excel doesn't do this on a clean install. There's something *else* that's involved, likely something that's fiddling with the clipboard.

Comment: That sounds like a clue, you have to copy cells one after another very quickly to get the error? Do you have any clipboard managers that could be pasting / saving the clipboard, or other similar programs monitoring the clipboard for stuff (like a downloader looking for URLs)?

Comment: Other software in PC takes up the clipboard.

Comment: I agree with the other comments but want to note that you should state your Excel version, because Excel 2016/365 has clipboard changes from earlier versions.  Also please note specifics such as your OS or if you're using it in Citrix.  Keep in mind that Excel generally uses the "office clipboard" unless another clipboard manager takes precedence, so that could be the source of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this happens when some other program on the computer "locks up" the clipboard. Here is the relevant paragraph from [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/theres-a-problem-with-the-clipboard-but-you-can/6720299f-1084-4104-93cc-abee9dcf7469) link.

> When Excel shows this dialog after a copy (CTRL+C) action, it means that another app has a lock on the system clipboard.  In this situation you can still paste within Excel.  However you cannot paste to another app like Word or Outlook which uses the clipboard.

I have no idea how to unlock the clipboard or even find what program is using it though. So any help will be appreciated on that one.

Comment: This seems like a useful answer, but regarding the final portion, perhaps consider posting that as a new, separate question. Older questions like this tend to be a bit lower traffic, so the chances of someone commenting with a solution seems less likely.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by pressing Windows Logo button + V which brings up the clipboard history,  The history was off so I turned it on and it fixed the issue.